# How to do restricted URL in Array and Checkout Page

Tags: php

I want to **restrict page** of **Check_out.php** and **my_account.php**. I have added these restriction on **top.php** like this!

```
$current = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $current;
$restricted = array("<a href='" . BASE_URL . "products/check_out.php'>Check Out</a>,
<a href='" . BASE_URL . "users/my_account.php'>My Account</a>");
$public_pages = array("login.php","signup.php");
```

It is not working fine! without login. Check out page is still opening!

Link below, when user clicked on it.
It need to check the condition like If user **login** then it goes to **check_out page**. Otherwise it goes to **singup.page**

```
<li><a href="<?php echo(BASE_URL); ?>products/check_out.php"> Check Out </a></li>
```

**Here is the code of condition, what i have done right now!**

```
if ($obj_user->login && in_array($current, $public_pages)) {
  $_SESSION['ref_url'] = $url;
  $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must <a href='" . BASE_URL . "/process/process_logout.php'>LOGOUT</a> to view this page";
header("Location:" . BASE_URL . "msg.php");
}

if (!$obj_user->login && in_array($current, $restricted)) {
 $_SESSION['ref_url'] = $url;
 $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must <a href='" . BASE_URL . "/login.php'>LOGIN</a> to view this page";
 header("Location:" . BASE_URL . "/msg.php");
}
?>
```

In Check_out.php , I have already set the table which displayed quantity, product name and total price

thanks!

Comment: you can use redirection on those pages

Comment: @Ali, why are you not using $_SESSION for checking either login or not?

Comment: just check the session on checkout page if not exist return on signup page

Comment: @devpro $_SESSION started top.php . information of shopping cart stored on session. so user has not yet login. thats why untill he/she signup or login. how it can be done!

Comment: @Ali, you are storing cart data without login? are you using any Framework for it??

Comment: in shopping cart. information getting from database! but add to cart info is coming through session. only problem right now. how to check session condition on check_out page. user is login or not . i am stuck right now @devpro

Comment: @ali, you must have a session variable like $_SESSION['session_userid'] , if user logged in by using your login page than set the user id that you get from your database... and on checkout page at top, check if(isset($_SESSION['session_userid']) && intval($_SESSION['session_userid']) > 0) execute your code else redirect on login page....

Comment: you must need to set userid in your session in login.php file. if user logged in session _userid should be greater than 0 else should be 0

Answer (score 0):

1. change your first line to this

   `$current = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`
2. change $restricted array to this

   `$restricted = array('check_out.php','my_account.php');`

Comment: yes done this! it restricted the check_out.php page! now how to redirect signup.php page

Answer (score 0):

In any of your none public php file add a check if your user is login if not then redirect to signup page.
Add your check in the top most of any none public php file.

```
//Make sure your session has started 
//Check the user if he/she is not logged in, assuming this will return true or false if the users session is set.
if(!$obj_user->login){
   //redirect to the sign up page e.g
   header("Location: signup.php");
}
```

Comment: righ! Now one thing confused. after signup.php . i have to return back to check_out.php page. if it comes through check_out.php , after singup or login.php

Comment: add the above code in your check_out.php that will check if the user is login .That code will check If he/she is not login then redirect to sign up page.

Comment: after signup.php , i want to redirect again to checkout page !  how ?

Comment: after signup make a session for the users currently signed up. after session has been created then use header("Location: check_out.php");

Comment: Glad that you got it :D